# How to initialize an empty LinkedList<T> in Dart?

Tags: dart, linked-list

I'm trying to create a linked list of type T in dart

```
var list = LinkedList<T>();
```

but the editor says

> 'T' doesn't extend 'LinkedListEntry'. Try using a type that is or
>   is a subclass of 'LinkedListEntry'.

Comment: Did you read the documentation for LinkedList? https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.0/dart-collection/LinkedList-class.html

Comment: i did but didn't understand the purpose tbh. does dart have a linked list implementation or not ? and if it doesn't what's the purpose of this class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basic example of usage:

```
import 'dart:collection';

void main() {
  var list = LinkedList<MyEntry>();
  list.add(MyEntry(1));
  list.add(MyEntry(2));
  list.add(MyEntry(3));
  print(list);
  print(list.last.previous);  
  list.last.previous.unlink();
  print(list);
}

class MyEntry extends LinkedListEntry<MyEntry> {
  final int id;
  MyEntry(this.id);

  @override
  String toString() {
    return '$id';
  }
}
```

Result:

```
(1, 2, 3)
2
(1, 3)
```

Answer (score 4):

The `LinkedList` class in the Dart platform libraries is, well, not a `List`.

It's a container for objects which implements `LinkedListEntry`, which means that the objects *themselves* have the `next` and `previous` links needed to implement a linked list. It's not provided by the `LinkedList` class.

You can use the `LinkedList` to contain any objects, you just have to create a helper class which you can put those objects into, a helper class implementing `LinkedListEntry` objects. For example:

```
class Entry<T> extends LinkedListEntry<Entry<T>> {
  T value;
  Entry(this.value);
}
// ...
main() {
  var ll = LinkedList<Entry<int>>();
  ll.add(Entry(42));
  ll.add(Entry(37));
  print(ll.first.value);  // 42.
}}
```

Answer (score 3):

It is worth noting that you must specify the type of element that will be added to your linked list. You are currently specifying `T` but `T` is not a class, it is an identifier representing a class. You need to replace this with `FooEntryClass` which is a class you define to be the object type you are adding to this list. This class must extend `LinkedListEntry` which is what the others were getting at when they said check the docs.

Your code would end up looking like:

```
var list = LinkedList<FooEntryClass>();
```

Further reading:
https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#generics

*FooEntryClass is an arbitrary class name I made up. You would need to define your own class and can pick whichever name you want.